# How to export custom characters or character by character via XML

Tags: xml, actionscript-3

I have provided an image below. I have managed to export a patch of test code on the right side of the image, but I want the layout to be similar to that of the left. I want to export characters such as {, :, [, ],,

Is there a way to export to XML in a structure similar to the left side? I want to avoid the automatic insertions (e.g. <, >, /).

Is there an equivalent way to do this in Haxe?

If not, what are my options?

Picture, comparison of what I want vs. what I have managed to export currently:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/XOUrz.png

Comment: This? http://krasimirtsonev.com/blog/article/as3-action-script-convert-xml-to-json-xml2json

Comment: I will be trying this! Thank you, seems this might be the only information I receive on the concern.

Comment: The thing about your picture, you have XML on the right and JSON on the left. JSON is **not** a form of XML, it is a separate data format (string representation of AS3 or JavaScript generic objects), you can convert one into another though.

Comment: How did you generate the XML in your picture?  If you wrote some code to write the XML, you can just use [JSON.stringify()](https://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/JSON.html) instead of writing the XML.  If you need to parse the XML and convert it into JSON, you could look into using [e4x](https://help.adobe.com/en_US/ActionScript/3.0_ProgrammingAS3/WS5b3ccc516d4fbf351e63e3d118a9b90204-7e72.html) to help you parse into an object structure, then using JSON.stringify on that.